# cast missed c# explicit conversion

Tags: c#, type-conversion, implicit, explicit, explicit-conversion

I've got trouble with type conversion with following code:

```
public class pr<T>
{
    private T tt;

    public pr( T value ) {
        this.tt = value;
    }

    public static explicit operator T(pr<T> op)
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    public static explicit operator pr<T> (T op)
    {
        return null;
    } 
}
```

Usage:

```
        byte value = 255;
        pr<byte> property = new pr<byte>(50);

        property = (pr<byte>)value; // no error here, works well test it throught debugger.
        value = (pr<byte>)property; // An explicit conversion exists are u missing cast?
```

Please tell me what i'm doing wrong. I'm just a begginer and rly don't understand what i supposed to do. I apologize for my bad english. Thank you.
P.S. implicit conversion works fine.

Comment: You are trying to set a `byte` type to `pr<byte>` with your cast of `property`. If you cast as such `value = (byte)property`, it should fix it.

Comment: Yeah my fault, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
value = (byte)property;
```

Modify second line as above. Your target type in `byte` not `pr<byte>`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
value = (pr<byte>)property; // An explicit conversion exists are u missing cast?
```

into

```
value = (byte)property; // An explicit conversion exists are u missing cast?
```